# How to argue that a series that isn't a power series is analytic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}}$.  Then $f$ converges in the unit disc.  I want to show that it is analytic in this region as well, but since it is not a power series I don't have any theorems to apply.  My only thought was to try and use similar reasoning as with power series: show that converges is uniform so that we can switch integral and sum to show that the integral of the series is 0, then apply Morera's Theorem.  But the problem is, according to Wolfram Alpha, $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{int}ie^{it}}{1-e^{int}}dt$ doesn't converge.

EDIT: To apply Morera's Theorem $\gamma$ should be closed path *contained* in the unit circle.  (It probably should have been obvious that the integral doesn't converge since the unit circle contains 1...).  So the above strategy does works (yay!) since the function is holomorphic in any closed disk with radius less than 1.

Comment: Of course the sum should start at $n=1$, not $n=0$. To show this is a power series, note that, if $|z|<1$, $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{kn}=\sum_{n\geqslant1,k\geqslant0}z^{n(k+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma_1(n)z^n$$ where $\sigma_1(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: How are you getting the first equality?

Comment: Any one of the five people who upvoted should feel free to answer

Comment: @Did How did you get the last equality?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd That’s just geometric series.

Comment: @Szeto ah oh course, thank you

Comment: @Szeto fix $m$, then number of times $x^{m}$ appears in the sum is number of ways of writing $m=n(k+1)$.  I'm trying to figure out way we don't double count divisors.

Comment: "I'm trying to figure out way we don't double count divisors" Sorry but which "double counts" are you alluding to?

Comment: @Did I'm good now, I see why we don't double count divisors.  That was cool, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $C$ be a compact subset of the open unit disk and let $M=\sup_{z\in C}|z|$. Then $M<1$ and, for each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$\left|\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}\right|=\frac{|z|^n}{|1-z^n|}\leqslant\frac{M^n}{1-|z|^n}\leqslant\frac{M^n}{1-M^n}.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{M^n}{1-M^n}$ converges, your series converges uniformly on $C$. Since this holds for every compact subset of $D_1(0)$, the sum of the series is analytic.

Comment: I was wondering what other theorems there are.  This is not one I think I knew.

Comment: Just to be clear: the theorem that I used here is due to Weierstrass and says that if a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of analytic functions converges uniformly to a function $f$ on each compact, then $f$ is analytic too.

Comment: After posting I realized that to apply Morera's Theorem I only need uniform convergence in some closed disk contained in the unit circle.  So the integral above probably does equal zero on such a closed disk.